# Some website don't load properly on Mac

Tags: facebook, macos, firefox, safari, gmail

First of all I am new to Mac. I am using a macbook pro with OS X 10.6.8 on a 2.4 GHx Intel Core 2 Duo. But the book has already been used, so I assume some settings have been changed.

Problem is that when I open a few websites, particularly facebook and google associated sites like gmail and documents, they don't load properly. With facebook it looks like if no CSS has been downloaded. Gmail dont show any icons and when I open a google doc like excel sheet and as soon as it tries to autosave, I can't make any further changes. Almost all other websites open properly. Moreover, I get a lot of security warnings by all browsers and I have to add almost all the sites to the exception list.

I have tested these sites on Safari 5.1.2, Firefox 10.0 and Chrome 17.0.963.79. Images are attached, please suggest something.

[image: facebook]
[image: GMail]
[image: Google Docs]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the file in Chrome cache system went wrong, it can be fix by deleting the all the cache files and reload the website.

The steps to clear cache files:

1. Chrome (next to your Apple icon) -> Clear browsing data...
2. Change the "Obliterate the following items from:" to "the beginning of the time"
3. Unselect all items besides "Empty the cache"
4. Press "OK"

then reload your problem sites, it should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

When I cleared Cache of Chrome browser, safari loaded facebook but without images. Firefox still don't load anything. Then I cleared cache of each browser and now everything is working fine.